# How to write a Java.IO.FileOutputStream into photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outputstream)?

Tags: android

Having trouble with File coding. This code basically save the bitmap file into android gallery.

```
Java.IO.File MyDirectory = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "MyDirectory");            
Java.IO.File MyFile= new Java.IO.File(MyDirectory , String.Format("Photo{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

Bitmap photo;
Bundle extras = data.Extras;
photo = (Bitmap)extras.Get("data")
```

How to save the photo (Bitmap) into MyFolder android gallery?
I have tried this to save the photo:

```
Java.IO.FileOutputStream outFile = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(MyFile);
photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outFile);
```

Error I received is when the photo is compress..

```
 error: Cannot convert from Java.IO.FileOutputStream to System.IO.Stream.
```

Sorry, I am very newbie in File coding. Any helps or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: @ItzHoudini Yes, this is my code:
using(Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(myFile))
{
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use alternative way to compress my bitmap (using MemoryStream) and here is my code.

```
using(Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(myFileString))
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
    myWebService.functionSave(stream.ToArray());
}

//myWebservice function parameter.
functionSave(byte[] fileStream)
{
    //... save your bitmap code using byte[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

public static void saveBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        String env = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String path = env + "/test.png";
        try {
            File f = new File(path);

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut);
            try {
                fileOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bitmap.recycle();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am writing in C# though, in the bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fileout) gives me same error:  cannot convert from Java.IO.FileOutputStream to System.IO.Stream...

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 var file = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
 photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 85, file);
```